# use intellij kotlin kt file in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, import, import-libraries

I have written a program using intellij and want to import the code into android studio but i can't find any tutorials that have this specifically.

I am only able to find using kotlin in andoid studio or convert from kotlin to java.

I know it will be easy and that I am not looking in the right places but could really do with a pointer, I have been trying to do it all day lol im starting to loose the will!

Thanks

Comment: What is the coding language of the project in IntelliJ? What have you tried doing specifically? What was the outcome?

Comment: sorry i put it in the tags but forgot the post :/  The program is written in kotlin, a standard kotlin file setup, imported one external library for webscraping information and displaying it. I have got the code working and now want to "insert" it into an android studio project change the println to display in the app some place and build into an apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you have a bunch of code files and wanna import your code into Android Studio, the easiest way is to just create a new Android Studio Kotlin project, copy your code files from your IntelliJ project to your new Android Studio project, then adjust the code for Android.

If you do it inside the programs instead of in the file explorer, it will even adjust the package names for you.
Here's what I mean exactly by inside the programs:
[image: IntelliJ]
[image: Android Studio]

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant lol.knew it would be easy... Couldn't see the wood for all the trees

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an Android application with the code that you write in IntelliJ. You can create an app in Android Studio and paste the code in the right place(should be in onCreate method) and manage the way that you will show the result. Also you can create an Android application in IntelliJ with the Android plugin.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but wasn't sure... Thanks for the tip!